# Hexagon Links in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie to front-end. I have created 6 hexagons on my page. I found this code online. I want to turn each hexagon into a link. How can I do this? I know it's probably pretty easy.

```
<div class="hexagons">
    <svg id="hex1"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg>
    <svg id="hex2"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg>
    <svg id="hex3"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg>
    <svg id="hex4"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg>
    <svg id="hex5"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg>
    <svg id="hex6"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg>

</div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none">
        <symbol id="hexagon" viewbox="0,0,300,300">
            <polygon points="150 0 280 75 280 225 150 300 20 225 20 75"></polygon>
        </symbol>
    </svg>

<!-- =============================================================================== -->
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them in a `<a>` tag?

Comment: You can add `<a>` elements inside an `<svg>`.

Comment: Add `<a href=["link]">` before each hexagon, and `</a>` after each. It's practically a fundamental of web development, so I suggest checking out the basics at [**W3Schools**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each `svg` in an anchor tag.

```
<div class="hexagons">
  <a href="#link1"><svg id="hex1"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg></a>
  <a href="#link2"><svg id="hex2"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg></a>
  <a href="#link3"><svg id="hex3"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg></a>
  <a href="#link4"><svg id="hex4"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg></a>
  <a href="#link5"><svg id="hex5"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg></a>
  <a href="#link6"><svg id="hex6"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap them in a `<a>` tag

```html
<div class="hexagons">
  <a href="#"><svg id="hex1"><use xlink:href="#hexagon"/></svg></a>

</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none">
        <symbol id="hexagon" viewbox="0,0,300,300">
            <polygon points="150 0 280 75 280 225 150 300 20 225 20 75"></polygon>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
```